# Помогите разобраться с кодом на Java

Tags: java

Всем добрый день. Я новичок, прошу сильно не пинать :)

Есть задача: Написать программу, которая вводит с клавиатуры строку текста.
Программа заменяет в тексте первые буквы всех слов на заглавные.
Вывести результат на экран.

Есть, как мне показалось хорошее решение:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();

        s = s.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + s.substring(1);

        boolean sign = false;

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == ' ') {
                sign = true;
            }

            if (sign && c != ' ') {
                s = s.substring(0, i) + s.toUpperCase().charAt(i) + s.substring(i + 1);
                sign = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Принцип я понял так: Сначала сразу делаем заглавной первую букву первого слова. Затем проходимся по каждому символу и как только находим пробел и при этом следующий символ не пробел, то берем то что уже имеется в строке + меняем следующий символ после пробела на заглавную букву.

**Вопрос: почему это работает?**

```
if (c == ' ') {sign = true;} // если пробел "sign = true

if (sign && c != ' ') // Почему это условие выполняется ??? Допустим мы вышли с первого условия с результатом sign = true. Тогда логично следующее условие предствить в виде if (с== ' ' && c != ' ') - но это бред!
```

Помогите это понять :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение переменной `sign` может повлиять на обработку символа на следующих витках цикла. Код внутри цикла можно записать немного по-другому, тогда не будет двойной проверки на пробел:

```
char c = s.charAt(i);
if (c == ' ') {
    sign = true;
}
else if (sign) {
    s = s.substring(0, i) + s.toUpperCase().charAt(i) + s.substring(i + 1);
    sign = false;
}
```

Вообще, не знаю как в Java, в Python изменение списка, по которому в данный момент происходит итерация - зло и приводит к многочисленным трудноуловимым багам.